# Getting Subview from another Subview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have my main window's content view set like this:

```
 newContentView = [[CutoutView alloc]initWithFrame:window.frame];
     [window setContentView:newContentView];
     [newContentView release];
```

Where CutoutView is the name of my subclass.  Now I want to add a subview to it so I did the following,

```
filterView = [[FilterView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 500, 500)]; 
    [newContentView addSubview:filterView];
    [filterView release];
```

that all works fine except now I want to call methods from my filterView subclass and I want to get it like this but it wont work.

```
FilterView *filter = [[NSApp delegate] contentView];
```

I read in the docs that by using contentView it only "returns the highest accessible NSView object in the window hierarchy"  So I tried adding the following to the addSubview

```
[newContentView addSubview:filterView positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:nil];
```

but that didnt work either any ideas as to what I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: I typically just add a property to keep track of views I want to access later.

Comment: ok I did `@property (nonatomic, strong) FilterView *filterView;` but how would I access that property in another class to get to its methods?

Comment: assuming it's part of your app delegate you would just get a handle to you application delegate like `MyAppDelegateClass *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` and then get the property off of it.

Comment: ok so for the mac it is `MyAppDelegateClass *appDelegate = [[NSApp sharedApplication] delegate];` and then I would do `[appDelegate filterView]` but to get to the methods what do I add to that last bit of code? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content view is really your CutoutView class so you should be using:

```
FilterView *filterView = [[[[[NSApp delegate] window] contentView] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

But two cleaner ways are:

1) Use IBOutlets to keep track of your views and assign them via IB.
2) Use tags:

```
filterView.tag = 101;
```

then use:

```
FilterView* filterView = [[[NSApp delegate] contentView] viewWithTag:101];
```

Comment: one quick question when I try to use a tag and I set it like `filterView.tag = 101;` its giving me the message, `No setter method 'setTag' for assignment to property` so what do i need to add? Thanks!

Comment: I have to apologise - it seems that NSViews don't have tags.  UIViews on iOS do have them.  Can a Mac programmer confirm that?

Comment: The docs say `Subclasses can override this method to provide individual tags, possibly adding storage and a setTag: method (which NSView doesn’t define).`

Answer (score 0):

ContentView is a method of your window not the app delegate, so if you have a window whose IBOutlet is "window" in your app delegate, then you need to use: FilterView *filter = [[[NSApp delegate] window] contentView];

Comment: Ok I added window] contentView]  But now when I try to get methods from my FilterView it crashes and says `-[CutoutView myMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1050415a0` which means that it is only accessing the main view subclass called "CutoutView" and not the sublcass that I want which is the subview called "filterView"